# vim mapleader command-t screwed up vim configuration

Tags: vim, plugins, configuration

In one of my scriptfiles I have definied some mapping with `,`, like

```
nmap ,t <ESC>:Todos<CR>:w<CR>
```

Currently I installed [command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025). During this process I set the mapleader in .vimrc

```
let mapleader=","
```

This screwed up my own mappings, so I removed mapleader from the configuration. Additonaly I [removed command-T](https://wincent.com/forums/command-t/topics/425) from my .vim directory. But unfortunatly this did not help.

When I typ now `,t` a split screen buffer opens with a kind of taglist inside. looks like this if i type `?` in this new buffer:

```
" <enter> : Jump to tag definition
" o : Jump to tag definition in new window
" p : Preview the tag definition
" <space> : Display tag prototype
" u : Update tag list
" s : Select sort field
" d : Remove file from taglist
" x : Zoom-out/Zoom-in taglist window
" + : Open a fold
" - : Close a fold
" * : Open all folds
" = : Close all folds
" [[ : Move to the start of previous file
" ]] : Move to the start of next file
" q : Close the taglist window
" ? : Remove help text
```

looks like a vim feature which was activated somehow. How can I get my `,t` working again with my mappings?

Comment: You probably didn't remove everything or a different plugin is overriding something.

Comment: was a different plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Could figure it out. Running `:nmap` showed me which function was map on `,t`. With this information I could find the **troublemaker**. Was the taglist-plugin.

works now again :)

Comment: `:verbose map ,t` would have told you what file the mapping was set in.

Comment: calm down. Problem is solved. Everything is fine and working.